# Python. Как вывести слов из списка

Tags: python, list

Как вывести слово `'привет'` и `'пока'`?
Условный код:

```
a = ['привет мир', 'пока мир']
```

Хотелось бы присвоить новую переменную этим словам, по типу:

```
b = a[0][0]
```

Comment: `b = a[0].split()[0]`

Comment: c, _, b, _ = sum((x.split() for x in a), []) переменная с равна 'привет' и переменная b равна 'пока'

Comment: c, b = map(lambda z: z[0], (x.split() for x in a))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так делать, если нужен список всех первых слов из элементов другого списка(не совсем понятно, нужно выводить первое слово только одного элемента или всех):

```
a = ['привет мир', 'пока мир']
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i.split()[0])
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Если только для этой задачи то можно использовать такой код:

```py
a = ['привет мир', 'пока мир']
b = a[0][0:6]
b1 = a[1][0:4]
```

в результате в переменной `b` будет `'привет'`, а в `b1` будет `'пока'`

`a[0][0:6]` - первые скобки это обращение к элементу списка, в данном случае `'привет мир'`, вторые скобки это срез строки, то есть символы с индексами от 0 до 6 включая, в данном случае `'привет'`.

Не совсем понятна задача, можно создать список из этих слов:

```py
a = ['привет мир', 'пока мир']
b = list() # создание списка b

for i in a: #перебор элементов в а в данном случае 'привет мир' и 'пока мир'
    b.append(i.split()[0]) # добавление через append строки i разбитой по разделителю по умолчанию пробел 

print(*b) # вывод развернутого списка b

# Вывод: привет пока
```

Можно через такой код.

Но если это конкретно про эту задачу, то лучше использовать такой код:

```
a = ['привет мир', 'пока мир']
b = ['привет', 'пока']
print(*b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чисто по приколу вариант без циклов и т.п.:

```py
a = ['привет мир', 'пока мир']
b, _ = zip(*map(str.split, a))
print(b)
# ('привет', 'пока')
```